# How to create a webpage on a shared network drive

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js

Our workplace has a shared network drive that everyone in our department has access to without explicitly requiring credentials. The link is something like
`myworkplace.com/mydept/archive/etc`

Anyone from my department can access this link via file explorer or even their browser. Currently, I use it by calling python scripts that exist on the drive by using

```
> pushd myworkplace.com/.../python/
> ./python.exe scriptPath/script.py arg1 arg2
```

The result is that it copies a set of files (arg1) from an SFTP server (arg2) onto this drive for everyone in the department to review via a new link/directory path. Now, I want to create a very basic webpage that others in the department can use to essentially pass arg1 and arg2 as input to this script and by the click of a button run this script themselves.

My research suggests that I should use node.js as client-side webpages cannot interact with the server-side scripts/tools without it. This requires serious network configs which is entirely out of the question as that is not our responsibility and the last thing I would want to do is get an angry email from the networking team. However, if me and others can easily pushd into the drive and run scripts from it, shouldn't there be something just as easy that I can do from a webpage? Maybe I can leverage the network config of the network drive itself?

I also believe that I may be misunderstanding the issue entirely, and that maybe I'm calling the script from the drive but actually running it locally, but my knowledge on networking is very slim so I'm not exactly sure what is really possible here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this rather simply

When I pushd into the network drive I can run the command

```
ipconfig
```

which returns the IP address of the drive. I used that as the host name and used port 8080. When running the node.js script I made sure to use those details as below

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const host = '11.111.111.111';
const port = 8080;

app.get('/Home', (req,res) => {
res.sendFile(<UNC Network path to HTML landing page >)
})

app.listen(port, host, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`))
```

When my colleagues and I typed '11.111.111.111:8080/Home' into our browser we were able to access the page and it's contents. I think this is the standard protocol for creating a website and I may have simply misunderstood the requirements.

The rendered HTML page contained a button that would call a different function in my node.js script which returned the output from my python script. See below

```
function myFunc(arg1, arg2){
    const spawner = require('child_process');
    const path = require('path');
    var dataToRead;

    //declare path to python executable
    const python_exe = path.resolve(<UNC path> + 'python/python.exe');

    //declare path to python script
    const python_py = path.resolve(<UNC path> + 'script.py');

    //create a process on server side calling the python executable to initiate python 
    //and pass the script and arguments as a list of paramaters
    const python_call = spawner(python_exe, [python_py, arg1, arg2]);

    //read the output from python script
    python_call.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        dataToRead = data.toString();
    }
}
```

And that's how I used a network drive to create a webapp that calls a python script and retrieves the results

P.S. I could not change the website name to be a string as that would require configuring the DNS to point to this IP and port, which is not something folks outside the network team have access to.